# adb connection not available, or was terminated - Android

Tags: android, android-emulator

First I have updated to Marshmallow and then Created AVD with Google API.
Once created it shows as

[image]

[image]

then after deletion when i run project

[image]

then my error getting

When i Run the APP (Shift+F10)

It shows the error as

at App tab :-

```
adb connection not available, or was terminated.
```

[image]

At emulator tab:-

```
D:\ADTSDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_One_API_23
emulator: WARNING: Increasing RAM size to 1GB
qemu: could not open disk image C:\Users\xxx\.android\avd\Nexus_One_API_23.avd/sdcard.img: Operation not permitted
```

[image]

I m unable to test my project with emulator and have searched on SO

I tried this also :

at cmd prompt :

```
adb kill-server & then 
adb start-server
```

Any solution to work with Android emulator surely appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `android:targetSdkVersion` to 23 did the trick for me. I was launching Android N preview (API23, same as Marshmallow), had the same error (`adb connection not available, or was terminated`).

Sometimes, I still get the error (e.g. if I opened Android Studio just now).
I open the Android Monitor tab [image: android monitor tab], wait for logs from the emulator to start appearing, and rerun my app